# PHP Ajax call to clear and populate a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi all I have a form on a web page, that for example contains a list of cars as seen below:

```
 <select name = "car" id="Cars" onchange="showForm()">
            <option value="0">Toyota</option>
            <option value="1">Audi</option>
            <option value="2">Suzuki</option>
</select>
```

Underneath this dropdown I also have another drop down for models:

```
<select id="models" onchange="showForm()">
            <option value="0">R8</option>
            <option value="1">Quattro</option>
            <option value="2">A6 hatchback</option>
</select>
```

however - I wish for the second dropdown with the car models to change when, a user has selected a different type of car brand.

I know I can make the select have an onchange method, and I can make an ajax call which will create a new array of models, however - I have no idea how to get the existing models out of the dropdown and to populate the dropdown with the new options. I am using PHP. eg of the onchange script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getModels(obj){
        var carTypeId = $(obj).attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/project/main/getModels",
            data: { 'carTypeId': carTypeId  },
            success: function(msg){
               //I don't know how to put the results back into the select box?
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated - my php result will be an array of arrays as seen below:

```
[models] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [modelName] => R8 ) [1] => Array ( [modelName] => A6 hatchback ) )
```

Comment: 1. make your API restful [i.e. no `POST` to a `getModels` route, but a `GET` to `/models`; 2. return a json array via `json_encode`, then iterate over it in jQuery and append `<option>s` to the desired `<select>` tag.

Comment: can I have an example please - would appending the models remove the models that are already options within the model select?

Comment: Appending does not remove anything [by definition]. Go try yourself, you have all the keywords to search google for now : ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need to update your select like

```
<select name = "car" id="Cars" onchange="getModels(this.value)">
        <option value="0">Toyota</option>
        <option value="1">Audi</option>
        <option value="2">Suzuki</option>
```

and for model

```
<select name = "model" id="models" onchange="showForm()">

</select>




<script type="text/javascript">

    function getModels(v){
       // var carTypeId = $(obj).attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/project/main/getModels",
            data: { 'carTypeId': v  },
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(msg){
                html = '';
              if(msg.model){
                for(i=0;i<msg.model.length;i++){
                   html += '<option value="'+msg.model[i][model_id]+'">'+ msg.model[i][model_name] +'</option>';
                }

               $('select[\'name=model\']').html(html);
             }

            }
        });
    }
$('select[name=\'car\']').trigger('change');
</script>
```

Now On Your php code i think you should push an model id too .. like

```
  <?php
   //$results is database result you fetched 
  $models = array(); 
  foreach($results as $row){  
     $models[] = array(
       'model_id' => $row['modelId'],
       'model_name' => $row['modelName']
     );
    }
    echo json_encode($models);

  ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - but what format would I return the msg.model as? is it the data json encoded?

Comment: thankyou makes much more sens - I will try this and mark you as correct after testing thankyou!

Comment: The OP wants to append to model dropdown.

Comment: ^ true - this is the best example of what to do on the PHP side however

Comment: aren't your dropdown values getting replaced rather than appending? yo u mentioned you want to append in the exinsting values i suppose?

Comment: then use .append from jquery instead of .html however i have updates something you can check on ajax call

Answer (score 2):

Return  your php result in this format

```
<option value="0">R8</option>
<option value="1">Quattro</option>
<option value="2">A6 hatchback</option>
```

Inside your success :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/project/main/getModels",
    data: { 'carTypeId': carTypeId  },
    success: function(msg){

    $('#models').html('');
    $('#models').html(msg);

    }
});
```

Not tested.hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In `/project/main/getModels` Iterate the array to form code with `<option>` then simply replace the html using jquery `.html()`

Example

if the ajax is returning say.

```
<option value="0">R8</option>
<option value="1">Quattro</option>
<option value="2">A6 hatchback</option>
```

Then in succes do this

```
$('#models').append(msg)
```

Comment: Hi I know this sounds stupid - but I am completely new to web programming how would I return each option one by one from the php side would this be a foreach of my array that echos "option value = 'x'>".model['modelName'].</option>

Comment: you need not return one by one. inside foreach you have to build a option cpmpletely.. foreach($array as $row){ $str .="<option value='value'>Modelname</option>"} in php file.

Comment: then simply echo $str?